# Cordova App not passing data using ajax form post

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

In the past week a hybrid app build using Cordova has stopped passing the data from a form.  The app works on Android.  The app used to work on iOS.  There are no errors testing with xCode and no server side errors.

When looking at the results in the mySQL table it is writing a completely empty row.

For form is submitted to a php file using ajax.

```
    // submit form to server
$('#formCustdata1').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var details = $('#formCustdata1').serialize();
    $.post('http://app.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/test1/send-data.php', details, function(data) {
        $('#phpDone').html(data);
        form.reset();
    });
```

Comment: remove cordova whitelist  plugin and reinstall it .

Comment: is it working fine in browser or not ?

Comment: Works fine in browser, works fine in Android, works fine in iOS prior to 9.3.4.  Broke with 9.3.5

Comment: have you tried to reinstall the cordova whitelist plugin ?

Comment: removed and reinstalled the cordova whitelist.  Still submitting blank data.

Comment: had you debugged you ajax request in browser that is it have data or not ?

Comment: Yes, works in browser.